# Django: wrong language preference

Tags: django, internationalization

I use Django to create a web project in two languages: english and german.
The default language of the document is english and I translated it in german by my own and created a .po file.

My idea is that if someone speaks german and the browser's locale is set to "de", Django should switch to german (the translation i provide). BUT in every other case, it should switch to english.

**The problem is that it exactly works the other way round and I have no clue why!**

Status quo: If the browser's locale is set to english, the website is displayed in english. but in any other case it is displayed in german.

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

_ = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
      ('en', _('English')),
      ('de', _('German')),
)
```

The middlewares are correctly set, the locale-path as well!
When I test the website, I clear all the cookies and the cache.
I tried to provide two translations (germand AND english, even though it is already written in english), but still the same effect.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See the get_language_from_request function. Understand how to choose the default language code.

Comment: Try to debug with the function. django/utils/translation/trans_real.py

Answer (score 0):

If you want your users to be able to specify language, make sure that LocaleMiddleware is enabled:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   ...
   'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
   ...
)
```

Then Django will look for the user's language preference in that order:

So the most straightforward way to set language explicitly in Django session, is to rewrite request.session['django_language']:

```
def someview (request):
    ...
    request.session['django_language'] = 'en'
    ...
```

Comment: But does this mean that even when the user is german speaking, the website will be displayed in english? -- yep, gave it a try. Even when i set the browser's locale to 'de', the interface is english

Comment: Why don't you put some dropdown or link of language selection , that will call your view and change language accordingly like most websites do.

Comment: I know this would be possible, but as most websites do, i want to detect the language of the browser AND provide a dropdown for language selection.

Comment: var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
alert(language); //works IE/SAFARI/CHROME/FF
detect language....

Comment: I tried to use `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` and a simple if-conditional to check the language code. the funny thing is that if i choose e.g. 'es' for spanish, the `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` string is 'de'! Only when i choose 'en' as my browser's locale, it is set to 'en'...