# Django "trans" template tag using wrong language

Tags: django, django-templates, translation

I have a site using Django 1.10 with German and English as available languages, where German is the source language. Dynamic content is translated with django-modeltranslation and for static strings I am using Django's built-in `trans` template tag.

I want Django to return the page in the visitor's preferred language. I have read [how Django discovers language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) carefully several times, and I think I have everything right. As I change my language settings in my browser, the value of the `LANGUAGE_CODE` variable when displayed in a template always changes accordingly, and also the dynamic content is always returned in the expected language by django-modeltranslation. Also the admin interface and extensions like rosetta and django-debug-toolbar switch their interface language nicely as expected. **It's only the `trans` template tag that is not picking my browser's language preference**. Instead, **it seems to directly resort to the initial value of the `LANGUAGE_CODE` variable as it is originally set in the settings file, without going through the algorithm described in the aforementioned link**.

The locale middleware is of course in place, and so are the *.po and *.mo files as well. The browser request headers also look fine. Because everything except the `trans` tag behaves as expected, I don't think that any of those is the problem. But for reference, here is my middleware settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

And my language settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('de', _('German')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]
```

Other possibly related posts on SO (yet a bit old):

- [How to set default language in Django for templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282074/how-to-set-default-language-in-django-for-templates)
- [Django: wrong language preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312669/django-wrong-language-preference)

Comment: Just for the records. You do `{% load i18n %}` at the top of each template which contains a `{% trans %}` tag, right?

Comment: @nik_m if you use {% trans %} without loading i18n you get an error, so it's safe to assume that yes, he's loading i18n

Comment: Have you run makemessages, translated your .po files, compiled them and relaunched the django processes ? hint : get rid of rosetta and manage your translations manually (with either a good text editor or something like POEdit) as part of your release process.

Comment: @nik_m Yes, I do include `{% load i18n %}` at the top. And I can tell that the `trans` tag is working by setting the `LANGUAGE_CODE` to `en` or `en-us`, the problem is that it _shouldn't_ translate when German is on top of English in my browser settings.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes, I have run `makemessages` and translated my .po files (with rosetta on the production server). On the production instance rosetta takes care of compiling them, while on my local instance I run `compilemessages` manually and have relaunched many times. So both on my local instance and on production, the .po files and the .mo files are in place, so it doesn't look like rosetta has harmfully interfered here. And in both places I experience the same behavior: translation happens (so the files are found), just not picking the right language correctly.

Comment: Just from curiosity: If, in one of your templates, put a `{% language 'de %}' at the top`, do the `{% trans %}` translate accordingly?

Comment: Interestingly, `{% language 'de' %}` doesn't affect the `trans` tag either, while it works as expected for everything else (dynamic content). I also tried out [language prefix un URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns) and again, everything was set to the correct language except the content translated with `trans`. `trans` stays with the initial value of `LANGUAGE_CODE`.

Comment: wrt/ rosetta, translating on the production server is an antipattern, your .po files should be part of the release (been here, done that...). But that doesn't solve the core problem, and I have to admit I'm at lost here. The only tjhing to do here would be to set a breakpoint  in the LocaleMiddleware or translations package to follow execution and find out where things go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured this out. I had .po and .mo files for English but not for my source language (German). Django of course doesn't know that my source strings are in German, but I was assuming that in case translations for a certain language are not found, it would show the original strings untranslated (i.e, in German in this case). Instead, it looks like before doing that, Django still looks for translations for the fallback language (the one defined as `LANGUAGE_CODE` in the settings, or English if none is defined). Only if it can't find *either* translations for the detected language *nor* translations for the fallback language it will show untranslated strings.

<s>So, my practical advice is: generate .po and .mo files for all available languages **including your source language**. And set your source language as `LANGUAGE_CODE` in the settings. You can then leave these translations empty if you want, so that the original strings will be shown</s>.

**Edit:** I also observed that my problem appears only if the source language is not the same as the fallback language (in my case, setting `de` as `LANGUAGE_CODE` everything still works as expected, but it was required that the site defaults to English despite the original strings being in German). So here comes my advice refined: *if your source language is different than the fallback language defined as `LANGUAGE_CODE` in the settings*, then you need to include the translations that correspond to your source language as well. This might mean providing translations files where all `msgid` and `msgstr` are identical... If you leave any `msgstr` empty, Django will try to find translation strings in the fallback language (which is different than the source language).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you depend on user's browser language settings. That's OK, but a good UX demands that you should offer the user a set of available language options. How do you do that?

Simply, follow [these directions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view).

After that, you should have the ability of selecting the preferred language via your website, regardless of the browser's settings. In your case, it should be either English or German. As you mention in your question, your setup should work pretty well. Give it a try please and if it didn't work I would be glad to refactor my answer!